# Docker: docker or docker.io?

Tags: docker

I've just realized I've installed two packages into my ubuntu:

```
apt list --installed | grep docker

docker/bionic,now 1.5-1build1 amd64 [installed]
docker.io/bionic,now 17.12.1-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
```

Which are the differences between them?

Could I uninstall one of them?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

docker and docker.io are older versions and must purge from your ubuntu:

https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#uninstall-old-versions

and install new docker-ce:

https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-docker-ce-1

docker and docker-engine or docker.io are remain on ubuntu repository but docker shift to two versions Docker CE [community edition] and EE [Enterprise edition]